# Could I use font-family BEFORE font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am curious about the right order of css rules font-family and font-face...

Could I use font-family before the font-face?

Like this:

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'inconsolatacyrmedium';
  }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'inconsolatacyrmedium';
    src: url('inconsolatacyr-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('inconsolatacyr-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I have tried and it works but may be it is wrong in some cases. I need the expert

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use @font-face before font-family, because browser reads css from top to end.

Comment: I try to use order that I am show before and it works!